# Error when starting the program after inserting AddTransient - when I remove it it works normally again

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.ILeilaoDao Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.LeilaoDaoComEfCore': Unable to resolve service for type 'Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.LeilaoDaoComEfCore'.)
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.ILeilaoDao Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.LeilaoDaoComEfCore': Unable to resolve service for type 'Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Alura.LeilaoOnline.WebApp.Dados.EfCore.LeilaoDaoComEfCore'.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options
    .UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=AluraLeiloesDB;Trusted_Connection=true"));

     services.AddTransient<ILeilaoDao, LeilaoDaoComEfCore>();
    
     services
         .AddControllersWithViews()
         .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
         {
             options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
         });
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your code where this is happening? Most probably you didn't register dependencies.

Comment: It looks like `AppDbContext` is not registered correctly (or at all) and it cannot be resolved while the `LeilaoDaoComEfCore` is constructed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind the error message is dependency injection container is unable to construct an instance of `LeilaoDaoComEfCore` because it requires an `AppDbContext` which hasn't been registered in the service container. When you remove `AddTransient`, the container no longer attempts to resolve `LeilaoDaoComEfCore` and thus doesn't encounter the missing dependency, which is why it works normally again.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that `AppDbContext` is registered in the service container before you register `LeilaoDaoComEfCore`. This is typically done in the `Startup.cs` file (or wherever you configure services) in an ASP.NET Core application.make sure that the connection string or any other required configuration for `AppDbContext` is properly set up.

Comment: I added it to the startup services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options
.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=AluraLeiloesDB;Trusted_Connection=true"));

another error came out but I got another error

Comment: @Jao33 which error you are getting

Comment: An error occurred while starting the application.
JsonReaderException: '}' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. LineNumber: 10 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(ref Utf8JsonReader json, ExceptionResource resource, byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)

FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file.
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)

JsonReaderException: '}' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. LineNumber: 10 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Comment: @Jao33  suggests there is a problem with a JSON file used by your application. This could be the `appsettings.json` file or another JSON file loaded for configuration. The error message `'}' is invalid after a single JSON value` indicates that there might be an extra or missing curly brace (`{` or `}`) in your JSON file. Check your JSON files (like `appsettings.json`) for any syntax errors. Ensure that all braces and commas are correctly placed.You can use a JSON validator tool to quickly identify and fix any syntax errors in your JSON files.